# Does anyone Remember me?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

They've talked about me since the history began.
I lived and I talked with the trees.
Then my punch, it was clocked. My attraction was knocked,
So I grew and I drew them to me.

It wasn't enough, looking back, and it was
In the sixties when I grooved and spun.
Even so, I seemed frigid, you might even say rigid
When I relaxed, my journey'd begun.

Quite nomadic and dandy, freakin' optical *candy!*
Those who listened to me were enthralled.
But my ass was too wide—I was fat!—so they fried
Me with lasers 'till Hollywood called.

Now I'm solid, it's stated—couldn't be more elated!
I still move when I feel it's allowed.
I'm not dying, don't worry, but I'm off in a hurry
To see what lies up in the clouds.

Comment: +1 for the amazing rhyming :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hm, I'm not sure but I think I remember you being

> portable media

They've talked about me since the history began.

> beginning with the spoken word and oral tradition

I lived and I talked with the trees.

> Writing and paper books, made from trees

Then my punch, it was clocked. My attraction was knocked,

> Punch cards have been used to store information well before computers were invented, eg for looms

So I grew and I drew them to me.

It wasn't enough, looking back, and it was
In the sixties when I grooved and spun.

> Not vinyl records but hard disks with spinning platters

Even so, I seemed frigid, you might even say rigid

> Hard disk drives (late 1950's-60's)

When I relaxed, my journey'd begun.

> Floppy disk drives (late 1960's)

Quite nomadic and dandy, freakin' optical candy!
Those who listened to me were enthralled.

> Optical media was introduced later, and portable CD players were used to play music

But my ass was too wide—I was fat!—so they fried
Me with lasers 'till Hollywood called.

> ?? Either a) Rewritable media until Hollywood introduced copy protection, b) movie production still used tapes and analog media because digital media lacked the capacity required, or c) the release of movies on optical media (dvd, bluray)

Now I'm solid, it's stated—couldn't be more elated!
I still move when I feel it's allowed.

> Solid state and hybrid hard drives, or flash memory in portable devices

I'm not dying, don't worry, but I'm off in a hurry
To see what lies up in the clouds.

> Cloud storage and data streaming services, which is replacing local storage media

Comment: Nothing in the timeline for "My attraction was knocked,
So I grew and I drew them to me?"

Comment: Best I can come up with is (rot13) nggenpgvba gb zntargvp gncrf

Comment: Yah, that's what I was going for. Plus for your ?? rot13(QIQ rapbqvat cvgf jrer znqr fznyyre ranoyvat n qvfp gb ubyq zber fgbentr, urapr Ubyyljbbq)